# Remove part from RSS Title

Tags: javascript, rss

Hi i'm not so experienced in coding, but i've tried hard to manage my rss feed item the way i want.
Now i'm stuck. I want to remove a part of the title (which is always — Aus Liebe zum Haustier).
Any idea how i get it done?

Thx for helping.
Best Jan

````
if(strpos($title, '— Aus Liebe zum Haustier')){
         $appeared = '— Aus Liebe zum Haustier';
         $title = str_replace('');
     }  
             <link><![CDATA[<?php echo $post->link; ?>]]></link>
             <guid><![CDATA[<?php echo $post->media->full; ?>]]></guid>
             <description><![CDATA[<?php echo $post->description; ?>]]></description>
             <title><?php echo $post->title; ?></title>
             <pubDate><?php echo (new DateTime($post->date))->format(DateTime::RSS); ?></pubDate>
             <enclosure length="<?php echo $length; ?>" url="http://terminator.edelwebwerk.de/safe_image/<?php echo $randomNumber . '_' . $ijk; ?>.jpg" type="image/jpeg"/>
</item>```
````

Comment: Isn't there a replace function in PHP? Something like `$post->title.replace("a", "b")` ?

Comment: Ah, [got it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php); `str_replace( $search, $replace, subject)`, which gives `str_replace('— Aus Liebe zum Haustier', '', $title )`. There. And I don't even PHP :)

Comment: this is what i've found.